# Determine when someone last logged in to a server from a key

Tags: ssh, logging, ssh-keys

I'm trying to track the last time a user logged into a Linux server with a certain key. So user `secure` has 5 keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, how can I track when each key was used and what IP was used to access the server?

Ideally I would be able to see that Key 1 was last used 5 days ago from 127.0.0.1, Key 2 was used 10 mins ago from 10.0.0.5, Key 3 and 4 were never used, Key 5 was used 2 weeks ago from 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to increase the `LogLevel` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to `VERBOSE` and restart sshd. This will cause sshd to log the fingerprint of the key being used to whichever log file your sshd is configured to use e.g.

```
Jan  7 22:46:17 host.lan sshd[5998]: Connection from 192.168.254.187 port 57062
Jan  7 22:46:17 host.lan sshd[5998]: Found matching RSA key: 54:d2:06:cf:85:ec:89:96:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b
Jan  7 22:46:17 host.lan sshd[5998]: Found matching RSA key: 54:d2:06:cf:85:ec:89:96:3c:a8:73:c7:a1:30:c2:8b
Jan  7 22:46:17 host.lan sshd[5998]: Accepted publickey for user from 192.168.254.187 port 57062 ssh2
```

It should be fairly straight forward to match the key fingerprint to the key and do what you want.